# Using a relative href for the stylesheet with XSLT is not working on macOS WebView (Xamarin.Forms 5.x)

Tags: css, xml, macos, xslt, xamarin.forms

Why is it that for my `WebView` XSL transform on macOS I had to set my `stylesheet` path this way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="ScheduleData/@CSSPath"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</link>
```

The CSS, XML and XSL files are all in the same folder on the Mac. Originally I put a hardcoded full path to the CSS file which worked:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/path to file/file.css"/>
```

But I realised this was not OK for users so I simply stripped the path, leaving just the file name:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="file.css"/>
```

But then the `WebView` would not find the style sheet. I even tried using `href="./file.css"` instead:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./file.css"/>
```

And it did not like that either. In the end I decided to add the full path, as determined at runtime, as an attribute to my XML file, and adjusted the XSL logic to use it (shown as the first example to my question) so that it could be correctly found.

That method works but it forces the user to have a XSL and CSS file with the same name (otherwise I don't know what path to build and pass in).

On Windows I use XSL etc all the time with IE and I have always been able to just use the file name and this would be relative to the XSL file. Yet the `WebView` refused to find it.

Is there a different way to specify the relative path in this context?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days it happened again. I ask my question here and stumble on the answer.

The issue was the [`HtmlWebViewSource`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.htmlwebviewsource?view=xamarin-forms) element:

```
HtmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource
{
    Html = TransformXMLtoHTML(xmlpath, xslpath),
    BaseUrl = StylesPath
};
```

I had to specify the [`BaseUrl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.htmlwebviewsource.baseurl?view=xamarin-forms). So now my XSL code looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ElderlyInfirm-Schedule-v1.css"/>
```

And all is well!